# Contact form fields to this custom HTML code

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7, custom-wordpress-pages

How can I add Contact Form 7 shortcode fields to custom HTML?

I also would like to keep the template (HTML) appearance.

For reference, this template form can be seen [in this link right here](https://codepen.io/krisantuswanandi/pen/KxrgeZ).

**My HTML code:**

```
<div class="background">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="screen">
      <div class="screen-header">
        <div class="screen-header-left">
          <div class="screen-header-button close"></div>
          <div class="screen-header-button maximize"></div>
          <div class="screen-header-button minimize"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="screen-header-right">
          <div class="screen-header-ellipsis"></div>
          <div class="screen-header-ellipsis"></div>
          <div class="screen-header-ellipsis"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="screen-body">
        <div class="screen-body-item left">
          <div class="app-title">
            <span>CONTACT</span>
            <span>US</span>
          </div>
          <div class="app-contact">CONTACT INFO : HELLO@CROWNSDEV.COM</div>
        </div>
        <div class="screen-body-item">
          <div class="app-form">
            <div class="app-form-group">
              <input class="app-form-control" placeholder="NAME">
            </div>
            <div class="app-form-group">
              <input class="app-form-control" placeholder="EMAIL">
            </div>
            <div class="app-form-group">
              <input class="app-form-control" placeholder="SUBJECT">
            </div>
            <div class="app-form-group message">
              <input class="app-form-control" placeholder="MESSAGE">
            </div>
            <div class="app-form-group buttons">
              <button class="app-form-button">SEND</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**Contact form 7 form:**

```
<label> Your name
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label> Your email
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> Subject
    [text* your-subject] </label>

<label> Your message
    [textarea your-message] </label>

[submit "Send"]
```

Comment: @Krishna Savani Any idea on how can I solve this? (ps.: I saw your help in a similar issue)

Comment: Is it HTML that you are trying to replicate or the design? If it is the design then you need to modify the CSS of Contact form 7 according to the HTML template.

Comment: @m4n0 I already added the css code to my website, now I need to implement the cf7 fields into the HTML code so that the form can work properly

Comment: You need to do the other way around. Modify the CSS according to the generated Contact Form 7 HTML.

Comment: @m4n0 by any chance would you have a link to show me how to do that? At least on how locate the css from the cf7